# How to change the preselected item's color from list in "Open resource"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, color-scheme

Using Darkest Dark theme on Eclipse CDT Oxygen, I have the preselected item from some dialogues like "Open resource" like this:
[image: unreadable pre selected item]

Where is the option to change this color? (if possible…)

Answer (score 0):

I've asked to the dev of Darkest Dark, see their answer here:
https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/preselected-item-in-some-lists-like-open-resource/#post-582599

TL;DR: Eclipse bug on Win7.